# Prevent React native input line breaks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-textinput

just wondering if there's a way to prevent React Native Text Input from breaking text into multiple lines when text is long [image]

Comment: are you using any specific library or the default textInput ?

Comment: it's the default one

Answer (score 2):

Just use multiline and numberOflines props like following ,

```
<TextInput multiline={false} numberOfLines={1}  />
```

Comment: Thanks! that was very helpful, already had it setup like that, that's why I was so confused, I did some tweaks here and there, the issue was that I needed some `vertical padding` along with the `multiline:false` and `numberOfLines:1`.